# Windows 10 UWP App Listview inside Listview DataBinding error

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I'm currently developing a Win 10 UWP app, and I'm having a weird error.

I've nested a ListView inside another ListView, like so:

(xaml)

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding VisualDayRepresentations}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding UserTimeRangeRepresentations}" SelectionMode="None">
                            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Background="{Binding Background}">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" FontSize="14"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

(c#)

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<VisualDayRepresentation> VisualDayRepresentations { get; set; }
}
public class VisualDayRepresentation
{
    public List<TimeRangeRepresentation> UserTimeRangeRepresentations { get; set; }
}
public class TimeRangeRepresentation
{
    public string Text { get; }
    public Brush Background { get; }
}
```

I created data and **everything is displayed correctly, everything works correctly when I run the app.** But weirdly I also get a lot of errors in my Visual Studio console, like these:

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Background' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Style'. BindingExpression: Path='Background' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Style'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid' (Name='null'); target property is 'Background' (type 'Brush')

Error: BindingExpression path error: 'Text' property not found on 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Style'. BindingExpression: Path='Text' DataItem='Windows.UI.Xaml.Style'; target element is 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' (Name='null'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Does anyone have any idea where these errors come from?

Comment: Tested your code, I can't reproduce your problem. You can test on other computer.

Comment: Try changing Text to Title. If that doesnt work try ItemsSource="{Binding VisualDayRepresentations.UserTimeRangeRepresentations}"